# LightInject GetInstance returning that cannot be used with type arguments

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, light-inject

I'm new to dependency injection and I find LightInject to start.
So I created 2 interfaces and implemented those interfaces into 2 classes. Now, I want to get a instance of Payment but compiler keeps saying that non-generic method 'ServiceContainer.GetInstance(Type) cannot be used with type arguments.

My interfaces are implemented in different files. I tried the way this guys says ([Getting Started with LightInject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29018354/getting-started-with-lightinject)) and works fine. But I think, somehow, as my interfaces and classes are in different files, it's not working i dont know why.

My codes are like this. IContract

```
namespace ConsoleApp1.Interfaces
{
    public interface IContract
    {
        int Discount();
    }
}
```

IPayment:

```
namespace ConsoleApp1.Interfaces
{
    public interface IPayment
    {
        void Pay();
    }
}
```

CrazyContract:

```
namespace ConsoleApp1.Classes
{
    public class CrazyContract: IContract
    {
        public int Discount()
        {
            return 3;
        }
    }
}
```

Payment and more important classe:

```
namespace ConsoleApp1.Classes
{
    public class Payment: IPayment
    {
        private readonly IContract _contract;

        public Payment(IContract contract)
        {
            _contract = contract;
        }

        public void Pay()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Discount {0}", _contract.Discount());
        }
    }
}
```

and my main which returns the error:

```
using ConsoleApp1.Classes;
using ConsoleApp1.Interfaces;
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var container = new LightInject.ServiceContainer();

            container.Register<IPayment, Payment>();
            container.Register<IContract, CrazyContract>();

            var p = container.GetInstance<IPayment>(); // the error is here

        }
    }
}
```

and the error:

```
error CS0308: The non-generic method 'ServiceContainer.GetInstance(Type)' cannot be used with type arguments
```

As you guys can see, I'm using Constructor Injection and I'd be very happy if any of you could explain what I'm doing wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I find a way to fix the problem.

We should explicitly that we need the package LightInject.

So, just put this code

```
using LightInject;
```

I dont really know why but this works

Comment: `GetInstance<T>` is probably an extension method that lives in the `LightInject` namespace.